# In inline editing in jqgird how to check whether any row is selected or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

In inline editing in jqgird how to check whether any row is selected or not?

I want to display error message "Please select a row!" when user click on edit without selecting any row.

@Oleg here is the code:

```
gridobject.jqGrid({
    url: getUrl,
    datatype: 'json',
    mtype: 'Get',
    colNames: arryDisplayCol,
    colModel: arryColSettings,
    pager: jQuery(pPagerName),
    rowNum: 20,
    rowList: [20, 40, 80, 100],
    height: '100%',
    viewrecords: true,
    loadonce: false,
    grouping: false,
    caption: caption,
    emptyrecords: 'No records to display',
    jsonReader: {
        root: "rows",
        page: "page",
        total: "total",
        records: "records",
        repeatitems: false,
        Id: "0",
    },
    sortable: {
        update: function (relativeColumnOrder) {
            var grid = gridobject;
            var currentColModel = grid.getGridParam('colModel');
            $.ajax({
                url: urls.Common.ArrangeGridOrder,
                type: 'POST',
                data: JSON.stringify(currentColModel),
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                success: function (response) {

                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                }
            });
        }
    },
    autowidth: true,
    shrinkToFit: true,
    multiselect: IsCheckbox,
    editData: myData,
    sortname: arrColSettings[0].name,
    editurl: urls.Admin.ProcessRequest,
    serializeRowData: function (postdata) {
        var tableNames = $("#grdData").getGridParam('caption').replace(' List', '');
        var columnNames = $("#grdData").getGridParam('colNames');
        var colNames = columnNames.toString();
        for (var i = 0; i < columnNames.length; i++) {
            var colName;
            if (columnNames[i] == "Id") {
                colName = "Id"
            }
        }
        if (!colName) {
            colName = columnNames[1].toString();
        }
        var sel_id = $("#grdData").getSelectedRowsIds();
        rowData = jQuery("#grdData").getRowData(sel_id);

        var colValue = rowData[colName];
        return { x01: JSON.stringify(postdata), x02: tableNames, x03: colNames, x04: JSON.stringify(jsonType), x05: colName, x06: colValue };
    },
    reloadAfterSubmit: true,

}).navGrid(pPagerName, {
    edit: false,
    add: false,
    del: false,
    search: false,
    refresh: true,
    refreshtext: "Refresh",
    beforeRefresh: function () {
        var tableName = $("#grdData").getGridParam('caption').replace(' List', '');
        ReloadGrid(tableName);
    },
});

gridobject.jqGrid('inlineNav', pPagerName,
                {

                    edit: true,
                    editicon: "ui-icon-pencil",
                    add: true,
                    addicon: "ui-icon-plus",
                    save: true,
                    saveicon: "ui-icon-disk",
                    cancel: true,
                    cancelicon: "ui-icon-cancel",

                    editParams: {
                        keys: false,
                        oneditfunc: null,
                        successfunc: function (val) {
                            if (val.responseText != "") {
                                var tableName = $("#grdData").getGridParam('caption').replace(' List', '');
                                ReloadGrid(tableName);
                            }
                        },
                        url: null,
                        aftersavefunc:null,
                        errorfunc: null,
                        afterrestorefunc: null,
                        restoreAfterError: true,
                        mtype: "POST",
                        alertcap: "Warning",
                        alerttext: "Please, select row"
                    },
                    addParams: {
                        useDefValues: true,
                        addRowParams: {
                            keys: true,
                            extraparam: {},
                            successfunc: function (val) {
                                if (val.responseText != "") {
                                    var tableName = $("#grdData").getGridParam('caption').replace(' List', '');
                                    ReloadGrid(tableName);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }


                }
    );
```

Comment: That is default enabled. have you tried it somehow?

Comment: You should post the code which shows what you tried. There are many ways to use inline editing, for example, `ìnlineNav`, call of `editRow` inside of `onSelectRow`, usage of `formatter: "actions"` and so on. Your question have any sense only in same *specific* usage of inline editing. So you should modify the text of the question and include more details. Moreover you should always include which *version* of jqGrid you use and which fork of jqGrid (free jqGrid, Guriddo jqGrid JS or old jqGrid in version <=4.7).

Comment: @Oleg Update the question with code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`inlineNav` automatically tests whether the row is selected or not. If the row is not selected then the message with the text "Please, select row" will be displayed. The default text come from `$.jgrid.nav.alerttext` defined in `grid.locale-en.js` file or other language file which you use. If your problem is in requirement of modification of the default text "Please, select row" to "Please select a row!" then you should use `alerttext` option of `navGrid` (the options should be defined on the same level as `refreshtext: "Refresh"`).